# Jacobian Calculation with Homographic Coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, image-processing

I'm trying to work my way through an [image processing paper (Creating Full View Panoramic Image Mosaics and Environment Maps)](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Edyer/cs534/papers/szeliski97.pdf) and am stuck on how the Jacobian is calculated, especially terms ($J_{17}, J_{18}, J_{27}, J_{28}$) in Section 3. The math is done in homography coordinates.

$$\boldsymbol{x}=[x,y,1]^T$$
$$D= \begin{bmatrix}
       d_0 & d_1 & d_2 \\
       d_3 & d_4 & d_5 \\
       d_6 & d_7 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}$$

The tilda $\sim$ indicates that the left/right side are equal to scale - the below matrix is element-wise divided by its final term.
$$\boldsymbol{x}''=[x'',y'',1]^T\sim(I+D)x =
  \begin{bmatrix}
     (1+d_0)x + d_1y + d_2 \\
     d_3x + (1+d_4)y + d_5 \\
     d_6x + d_7y + 1
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
This yields:
$$\boldsymbol{x''}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \frac{(1+d_0)x + d_1y + d_2}{d_6x + d_7y + 1} \\
     \frac{d_3x + (1+d_4)y + d_5}{d_6x + d_7y + 1} \\
     1
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
Now taking the Jacobian w.r.t $d=[d_0,d_1,...,d_8]^T$
$$J_d(x)=\frac{\partial{x''}}{\partial{d}}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
     x & y & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -x^2 & -xy \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & x & y & 1 & -xy & -y^2
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
I can see how the the terms in columns 1-6 could be calculated from $(I+D)x$ but not from $x''$, moreover the last 2 columns make absolutely no sense to me.
Also its possible $\boldsymbol{x}''=[x'',y'']$ as it would explain $J$ having 2 vs. 3 rows. The paper's vague there.